# Datepicker for ROR 4 best_in_place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, best-in-place

I would like to implement a datepicker for my app.

I went through the bates calender railcast, but I need something similar to that where it is possible to use it in `rails4` with backend `mongodb`.

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
<%= best_in_place employee, :mydate ,:type => :date %>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: `//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui` inside application.js    `<%= best_in_place employee, :mydate ,:type => :date %>`  inside form  `$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );` inside JS

Answer (score 2):

according to this issue on github issue for the gem https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/issues/68 the datepicker will only work with rails 3.X verisons.

Comment: This is not an answer. please use comment functions for remarks like that.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation to comment, and this answers his question sufficiently (as in, its not possible with rails 4).